# Compare property of custom class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a UIViewController which takes multiple ChildViewController.
Every ChildViewController is from my custom Class TaskViewController.

```
class TaskViewController:UIViewController{

let task:Task

init(task:Task) {
    self.task = task
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
 }

}
```

Now in my UIViewController I want to get the index of the child with a specific task, so I made this function

```
private func getIndexFromLastOpenedTaskViewController() -> Int?{
    guard let lastOpenedTask = process.tasks?.first(where: {!$0.isFinished}),
          let childTaskViewController = self.children as? [TaskViewController],
          let indexOfLastOpenedTaskViewController = childTaskViewController.firstIndex(where: {$0.task == lastOpenedTask}) //Error: UIViewController has no member 'task'
    else {
        return nil
    }
    return indexOfLastOpenedTaskViewController
}
```

I explicit cast my child view controllers to an array of TaskViewController. Why I can't access my property "task" ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: While creating a reproducible example I found a major mistake. I compared 2 different types with same meanings. Now it is working

Answer (score 0):

To compare custom objects you need to confirm to `Equatable` protocol. This protocol allow an object can be comparable.

Please refer the below example.

```
struct Person: Equatable {
 var name: String
  var age: Int

  static func ==(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
    return (lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.age == rhs.age)
  }
}
```

The above is the `person` structure which confirms `Equatable` protocol.

```
let jhon = Person(name: "Jhon", age: 15)
let cena = Person(name: "Jhon", age: 15)

if jhon == cena {
  print("Yeahh...its Jhon Cena!!")
} else {
  print("Both person are not equal")
}
```

The output will be...

> Yeahh...its Jhon Cena!!

```
let p1 = Person(name: "P1", age: 15)
let p2 = Person(name: "P2", age: 25)

if p1 == p2 {
  print("P1 and P2 aare equal")
} else {
  print("P1 is not equal to P2")
}
```

The output will be...

> P1 is not equal to P2

Hope this will help you to understand this protocol.